# Heap corruption while reading a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ifstream, ofstream

Visual Studio reports a possible heap corruption while debbuging the very beginning of my program. What this piece does is reading a .txt file to provide a list of strings to choose from.

The for loop goes smoothly until the end when program terminates and the error is thrown.

I'll also provide all functions called (if necessary).

```
int main() {
title_board(NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL);

// settings file
open_file(DEFAULT_SETTING);
bool generate_mistake_log=read_bool(16);
bool show_instructions=read_bool(10);
int pass_threshold=read_int(13);
t_direction trans_dir=read_t_dir(7);

int sett_lines=lines_count(DEFAULT_SETTING);
int library_verse=sett_lines-LIB_START_VERSE;
string *file_library=new string[library_verse];
for (int i=0; i<sett_lines; i++) {
    file_library[i]=read_string(i+LIB_START_VERSE);
    cout << i+1 << ". " << file_library[i] << endl;
}
string FILE_NAME;
cout << "\nFILE INDEX: ";
int file_ind;
while (!(cin >> file_ind)) {
    cout << "MISMATCH IN FILE INDEX: ";
    reset_cin();
}
```

Function *lines_count* and *read_string*

```
string read_string(int verse) {
open_file(DEFAULT_SETTING);
// it just opens a file, works fine
string temp_var;
for (int i=0; i<verse; i++)
    getline(WordsFileInput, temp_var);
close_files();
return temp_var; }

int lines_count(string file_name) {
open_file(file_name);
int a=0;
string * temp_str = new string;
while (getline(WordsFileInput, *temp_str))
    ++a;
close_files();
return a; }
```

[This is the output right before the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hMrm.png)

And this in turn is how my .txt file looks like.

> LEGEND:
>
> 1 = target -> mother
>
> 2 = mother -> target
>
> 3 = random
>
> VARIABLES:
>
> VAR NAME: translation_direction
>
> 1
>
> VAR NAME: show_instructions
>
> false
>
> VAR NAME: pass_threshold [%]
>
> 75
>
> VAR NAME: generate_mistake_log
>
> true
>
> FILES LIBRARY:
>
> files/dates.txt
>
> files/isis.txt
>
> files/music.txt
>
> files/farm.txt
>
> files/feminist.txt
>
> files/food.txt

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
int library_verse=sett_lines-LIB_START_VERSE;
string *file_library=new string[library_verse];
```

You just allocated the `file_library` array. The `file_library` array's size is `sett_lines` minus `LIB_START_VERSE`, whatever it is. That's what these two lines of code say. You didn't show what `LIB_START_VERSE` is set to, but it's fairly likely to be some positive number, greater than zero. The upshot of this all is that the size of the array is `LIB_START_VERSE` less than the `sett_lines` value.

```
for (int i=0; i<sett_lines; i++) {
    file_library[i]=read_string(i+LIB_START_VERSE);
```

... and you immediately proceed to initialize the first `sett_lines` verse entries in the `file_library` array.

You should be able to figure out the rest of the bug in your code all by yourself.